# How To Set Different 'Specific' Styles to The Same React Component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For ex, I have one button component, and I make 3 instances of it. I want them all to have the same underlying structure, but different colors. In my style sheet I don't want to copy and paste the many CSS properties already specified in one property, and just change the 'color'. How can I have it take in the defaultStyle AND override the color property?
Inside parent:

```
<Button color="green">
<Button color="red">
<Button color="blue">
```

Inside child Button:

```
return <button className={classes.btn}, {classes.props.color}>A Button</button>
```

Comment: how about `return <button className={classes.btn} style{{color:props.color}}>A Button</button>` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, give them all the same class name and then just a unique id to change their colors with.

```css
.app-button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#green-btn{
  background-color: green;
}

#red-btn{
  background-color: red;
}

#blue-btn{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="app-button" id="green-btn">green</button>
<button class="app-button" id="red-btn">red</button>
<button class="app-button" id="blue-btn">blue</button>
```